# Set Fn::ImportValue for environment variables in AWS::Lambda::Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

How can I set Fn::ImportValue for environment variables in AWS::Lambda::Function,
I tried:

```
  Environment:
    Variables:
      VAL1: Fn::ImportValue: "SOME_OUTPUT"
```

But i get "Template format error: YAML not well-formed"

Comment: `Fn::ImportValue` should be under they key `VAL1`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    VAL1:
      Fn::ImportValue: NAME-OF-EXPORTED-VALUE
```

See: [Fn::ImportValue - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    VAL1: {Fn::ImportValue: "SOME_OUTPUT"}
```